# Modify title text size in MaterialTimePicker

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, android-timepicker

I am trying to change the the text size of the title in a `MaterialTimePicker` but I've had no luck so far in finding the right attribute to modify in the `styles.xml` file for my project. I found that setting `textAppearanceButton` within my application's theme allowed me to change the button size and various other attributes allowed me to change the color theme as documented [here](https://material.io/components/time-pickers/android#theming-time-pickers), but I haven't found any documentation related to changing the title in any way. Is it possible to modify the title's text size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a themeoverlay specific to the time picker overriding the **`textAppearanceOverline`** attribute:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.TimePicker" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TimePicker">
    <item name="textAppearanceOverline">@style/TextAppearance.App.TimePicker.Title</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.App.TimePicker.Title" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.TimePicker.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

Then you can set this theme using:

```
    val picker =
        MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
            .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H)
            .setHour(12)
            .setMinute(10)
            .setTheme(R.style.ThemeOverlay_App_TimePicker)
            .build()
```

[image]

You can also set globally the specific theme to the time picker adding in your app theme:

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
    ...
    <item name="materialTimePickerTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.TimePicker</item>
</style>
```

**Note**.
Starting with `1.5.0-alpha03` you have to use the **`materialTimePickerTitleStyle`** attribute instead of  `textAppearanceOverline`:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.TimePicker" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TimePicker">
    <item name="materialTimePickerTitleStyle">@style/TextAppearance.App.TimePicker.Title</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.App.TimePicker.Title" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.TimePicker.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Oddly enough, I thought I had already tried setting `textAppearanceOverline` in my application's theme globally. But, for reasons I must not understand yet, it didn't change the title size for the time picker. Thanks for the concise answer!